# JRebel can't find Glassfish 5.1 (Netbeans)

Tags: glassfish, jrebel

[image: Text]

JRebel stopped reloading my app (even after redeploy) and it seems that my glassfish isn't on its list.

Any idea?

Edit: It says 5.0, but its a 5.1 glassfish version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem by adding -agentpath manually to JVM options (glassfish)